# Angular instead of radial probability density in spherical coordinates

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, probability, geometry, calculus

By the Born rule in Quantum Mechanics, a state's complex wave function $\Psi(x,t) \in L^2$ gives probabilities when we take its complex norm $\overline\Psi(x,t)\cdot\Psi(x,t) = |\Psi(x,t)|^2$. In this case, since I'm using the cartesian spatial wave function, the probability of finding the particle that is in the state $|\Psi\rangle$ in a small region around $x$ at time $t$ is:
$$|\Psi(x,t)|^2\,dx$$
Now, say I have the spatial wave function for the ground state of hydrogen, $\psi_{100}(r,\phi,\theta) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi a^3}}e^{-r/a}$, which is given in spherical coordinates (where $\phi$ is measured azimuthally). If I now want to know the probability of finding the particle in a small region around a certain radius, I turn out to have to consider a thin shell of radius $r$ as follows:
$$P=|\psi_{100}(r,\phi,\theta)|^2 dV = |\psi_{100}(r,\phi,\theta)|^2d\left(\frac{4}{3}\pi r^3\right)=|\psi_{100}(r,\phi,\theta)|^24\pi r^2dr$$
... and thus, if $\frac{dP}{dr}=f(r)$ is the radial probability density, we have $f(r)=\frac{1}{\pi a^3}e^{-2r/a}4\pi r^2$.

However, what if I want the probability densities $g(\phi)$, $h(\theta)$ or even $k(\phi,\theta)$? As an analogue to a thin spherical shell, I can only imagine constructing thin, outward-beaming rectangles with volume
$$dV = r^2\sin(\theta)\,d\theta\,d\phi\,dr = d\Omega\,r^2\,dr$$
and thus, presumably, if I only want to vary $\theta$ and $\phi$, summing those volumes like you would for the full-solid-angle shells:
$$dv = d\Omega \int^r_0r^2\,dr = d\Omega\,\frac{r^3}{3}$$
But now, what is $g$, $h$ or $k$? How, for one, do I sneak the last result into $P=|\psi_{100}(r,\phi,\theta)|^2\,dV$?

More generally, how does one go about this kind of converting to specific probability distribution variables for *any* wavefunction in spherical (and, while we're at it, cartesian) coordinates? I'm aware that in probability theory, doing a change of variables from a single to another single variable is always based on the equation $f(x)dx = g(y)dy$, but in this case, I'm stuck.

Comment: I have corrected one point in your notation.  The angular integration measure $d\Omega=\sin\theta\,d\theta\,d\phi$ already contains the $\sin\theta$ factor from the expression for $dV$ in spherical coordinates.

Comment: Ah, yes, thanks for that.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know the probably density $k(\phi,\theta)$ for the particle to be located in at an angular position $(\phi,\theta)$, you have to integrate out the radial coordinate:
$$k(\phi,\theta)=\int_{0}^{\infty}r^{2}\, dr\,P(r,\phi,\theta)=\int_{0}^{\infty}r^{2}\, dr\,\left|\Psi(r,\phi,\theta)\right|^{2}.$$
For an $S$ state, this is not very interesting, because the wave function is independent of the angles, and thus
$$k_{n00}(\phi,\theta)=\int_{0}^{\infty}r^{2}\,\left|\psi_{n00}\right|^{2}=\frac{1}{4\pi},$$
but for wave functions with nonzero angular momentum, you will get a nontrivial function
$$k_{nlm}(\phi,\theta)=\left|Y_{lm}(\phi,\theta)\right|^{2},$$
where $Y_{lm}(\phi,\theta)$ is the spherical harmonic that represents the angular part of the wave function when it is in an angular momentum eigenstate.

Comment: That's interesting. I do remember something along the lines of this from when I studied multivariate probability theory. I'm wondering, then: is it just a coincidence that the $d$-method I used for the radial probability distribution is equivalent to integrating over the entirety of angular space (giving $4\pi$, and leaving the $r^2$ from the Jacobian)? Also, I'm not quite sure what's happening between the second equality: isn't there some infinitesimal factor (like $d\Omega$) we're forgetting there, for $|\Psi|^2$ to count as a probability distribution?